# How to add union all in codeigniter datatables query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

I am using codeigniter 2.1 version.In this i have try to write data tables query with union all.I need both query values.But it not working,my query is given below,

```
$this->load->library('datatables');
$this->datatables->query("select sales.id as id, sales.date, sales.customer_name, sale_items.product_name, sales.depositcard_amt from sales join sale_items on sale_items.sale_id=sales.id where sales.customer_id = $user and sales.branch_id=$branchid and sales.depositcard_amt != 0.00 UNION ALL select deposit.credit_on, deposit_details.customer_name, deposit_details.package_name, deposit.total_amount from deposit join deposit_details on deposit_details.deposit_id=deposit.id where deposit.customers=$user");
        $this->datatables->add_column("Actions", 
            "<center></center>", "id")
        ->unset_column('id');
       echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

Now i have corrected the union all issues, but it not working in datatables. But when i check directly in sql it is working.

```
$this->datatables->query("select sales.id as id, sales.date as date, sales.customer_name, sale_items.product_name as pname, sales.depositcard_amt as debit, 0 as credit from sales join sale_items on sale_items.sale_id=sales.id where sales.customer_id = $user and sales.branch_id=$branchid and sales.depositcard_amt != 0.00 group by sales.id UNION ALL select deposit.id as id, deposit.credit_on as date, deposit_details.customer_name, deposit_details.package_name as pname, 0 as debit, deposit.total_amount as credit from deposit join deposit_details on deposit_details.deposit_id=deposit.id where deposit.customers=$user");
```

Please give any suggestion to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is with `UNION ALL` and different column list. `5` vs `4` and probably datatypes too.

Comment: ok. How can i solve this one, pls give any idea. I need these values in single query.

Comment: `UNION ALL` requires to have the corresponding columns list in both statements i.e. number of columns and datatypes (they could be implicitly casted)

Comment: ok i'll change it and let you know.

Comment: i have correct the union all issues, but not working in datatable format.